# Determine whether or not the topological spaces are homeomorphic or not

Tags: general-topology

• $(X, τ_X)$ where $X = \{(x, y) ∈ \mathbb{R}^2: x^2 +y^2 = 1\}$ with the topology $τ_X$ induced by
the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$
;

• $(Y, τ_Y )$ where $Y = \{(x, y) ∈ \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2 −y^2 = 1\}$ with the topology $τ_Y$ induced by
the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$
.

Comment: A general tip is: Try to visualize your topological spaces. Here, you can actually draw $Y$ and $X$ in the plane. What's your guess, are they homeomorphic or not? Also, have you learned about connectednes yet?

Comment: I think the top one is a circle and the bottom a hyperbola so I think they aren't homeomorphic but I don't understand how to rigorously show it.

Comment: See my edits to this question for proper MathJax usage. $$ X = \{(x, y) ∈ \mathbb{R}^2: x^2 +y^2 = 1\} $$ The entire expression is in MathJax, including the $\{\text{curly braces}\}. \qquad$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the standard argument saying that homeomorphisms preserve connectivity/path-connectivity. I want to give a related, but slightly different proof.

Note that $$\Bbb S^1 = \{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 \mid x^2 + y^2 =1\}$$ is the circle. It admits a continuous surjection given by
$$f:\Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb S^1, t \mapsto (\cos t, \sin t).$$

On the other hand the hyperbola $$X = \{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2 \mid x^2 -y^2 =1\}$$ can be decomposed into the two disjoint subspaces
$$Y_{-}=\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 \mid x^2-y^2=1, x\leq -1\}$$ and $$Y_{+}=\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 \mid x^2-y^2=1, x\geq 1\}.$$

Let $g:\Bbb R \rightarrow Y$ be any continuous map. Postcomposing it with the projection onto the $x$-coordinate
$$\pi_x:Y\rightarrow (-\infty, -1]\cup[1,\infty) \subseteq \Bbb R, (x,y) \mapsto x$$
we obtain a continuous function $g‘:\Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R$. Note that the image of $g‘$ indeed lies in $(-\infty,-1] \cup [1,\infty)$!

Now assume that $g‘$ admits some $t_{-} \in \Bbb R$ with $g‘(t_{-}) \in (-\infty,-1]$ and some $t_{+} \in \Bbb R$ with $g‘(t_{+})\in [1,\infty)$. By the *intermediate value theorem* then 0 is in the image of $g‘$ as well, a contradiction!

But this shows that the image of $g‘$ is contained either in $(-\infty,-1]$ or in $[1,\infty)$. Thus the image of $g$ is contained either in $Y_{-}$ or in $Y_{+}$. But this makes it impossible for $g$ to be a continuous surjection $\Bbb R \rightarrow Y$.

On a final note, if there were an homeomorphism $\Bbb S^1 \cong Y$ then precomposing it with the continuous surjection $f:\Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb S^1$ would yield a continuous surjection $\Bbb R \rightarrow Y$, which we proved to be impossible.

Comment: Is there any way to do this by defining a function $f :X\rightarrow Y$ and then show that the function is a continuouus bijection and if so how do I define this funtion

Comment: I am unaware of such a function. I think the easiest way to show what you are supposed to show is by using connectivity or by using my argument above.

Answer (score 1):

The map $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to X$, $f(t)=(\cos t,\sin t)$ is continuous and surjective, so $X$ is …

Consider $Y=(Y\cap Z_+)\cup(Y\cap Z_-)$, where
$$
Z_+=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x>0\},
\quad
Z_-=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x<0\}
$$
so $Y$ is not …

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Look at connectedness. Two topological spaces that are homeomorphic are either both connected or both disconnected.